# How many times is a simple snippet parsed?

Tags: javascript

When is it dynamically compiled.  Not too sure on correct terminology.  But for this snippet below, it is at least twice as the IIFE does not run until you call test.  In general, in simple terms, what is the process for dynamic compilation?

```
(function(){

    function test() {

        var T = (function(){
            // does not run until you call test
        }());

    }
    test();

})();
```

Comment: How do you expect a function run without calling it?

Comment: There is not really a difference between having an IIFE (like inside `test`) and defining the function before execution (like `test`)... I'm not really sure what you want to know. Code is parsed only once in any case.

Comment: @Felix - I don't understand what you are saying in relation to how many times that small snippet is parsed.

Comment: ...there is really no difference between calling a function or using it as an IIFE...is what you are saying...

Comment: You mentioned IIFE in relation with code parsing and I'm just saying that they don't have any influence on this. Or maybe I misunderstood what you said?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand exactly what you are looking for, but the entire snippet would be parsed a single time and stored as an Abstract Syntax Tree (or compiled to some kind of byte code by a modern JavaScript engine). The code that contains your comment would then be executed a single time when you call `test`.

Comment: As a side...when are function hoisted?

Comment: @Hiro: Function **declarations** are always hoisted.

Comment: It think you mean function definitions ( or declarations have you ) are hoisted while function expressions are not.

Comment: In compiled languages declarations and definitions are different...but there isn't really a correlation for declarations in JavaScript...

Comment: any online resources for dynamic compilation?

Comment: @Hiro: *"It think you mean function definitions ( or declarations have you ) are hoisted while function expressions are not"* Yep. *"There are no declarations in JavaScript"*: That's at least the technical term: http://es5.github.com/#x13.

Comment: @Felix - that is boss!  +1 for quoting ES5.  +1 for providing annotated version.